# When I user Java agentmain，the target jvm machine throw exception ClassNotFound

Tags: agent

i create a agentmain,and the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF has Agent-Class: cn.text.agent.AgentMainAgent
and the className is correct

then in other project send virtualMachine.loadAgent("xxxx.jar");

the target  jvm machine throw a exception

Exception in thread "Attach Listener" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cn.text.agent.AgentMainAgent

i want the target jvm machine success load the agent